# delays within for loop - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to set a delay within a for loop in an iphone app. Basically I'll have a for loop with a few actions and I want a 1 sec delay between each action:

for loop { action 1, delay 1sec, action 2, delay 1sec, action 3, delay 1sec}

How would I code this?

Comment: May be you want to use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)]`? NSTimeInterval in secs.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (loop) {

    [self action1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(action2) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(action3) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!!

**Edit**

Try this.. It will finish up running the current method and move to the next.

```
for (loop) {

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(action1) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(action2) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(action3) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: I manage to get a delay before calling (void)action2 however it is not returning to the for loop to then delay and call (void)action3. How do I return to the for loop after completing (void)action2 etc?

Comment: Updated!! Try this!! Or if you want to use sleep (), check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956175/when-i-really-need-to-use-nsthread-sleepfortimeinterval1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't involve a for loop but will take a list of actions and perform them with increasing delays.

```
NSArray *selectorStrings = @[ @"action1", @"action2", @"action3" ];
[selectorStrings enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString((NSString *)obj);
    NSTimeInterval delay = (NSTimeInterval)idx;
    [self performSelector:selector withObjet:nil afterDelay:delay];
}];
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.